# Remove Table Row by Class Name - Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I've looked through so many forum posts about this simple piece of code. And tried many variations and methods with nothing working.

I have a script that builds a table based on a database query. I limit it to 10 results and provide forward and back buttons to go to other results from the database. When you press the next button, I need it to delete all the current table rows so it can recreate them with the new results of the query. I am using the following code to remove the rows;

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('shiftTrRow')) {
    table = document.getElementById('resultsTable')
    deleteRow = document.getElementsByClassName('shiftTrRow');
    table.removeChild(deleteRow);       
}
```

I use the if case to check if there are any rows to delete, I've added an alert to test if there are rows discovered and this works.

When I run the code I receive the following error on the line:

```
table.removeChild(deleteRow)

Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

I've looked up the error code and it explains that the element couldn't be found, but this cannot be the case since this code will only execute if the element is found. If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or a better way to do this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: deleteRow = document.getElementsByClassName('shiftTrRow')[0];

?

Comment: Just tried that and still receive the same error. What is [0] for exactly?

Comment: 8 minutes and nobody suggested jQuery? WOW!

Comment: I've written all the scripts using pure JavaScript I wasn't sure if you can or how you can add jQuery into the middle of JavaScript though if I remember right you can interchange between the two, but anyway I haven't started learning any jQuery yet as I started with JavaScript only and would prefer to master that first.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, it's just that usually somebody suggests dropping it all and rewriting the whole thing with jQuery instead of giving a proper answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('shiftTrRow')
                   ^
```

returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Nodelist), i.e. an array of elements. You will need to loop over them and remove every of them on its own (but watch out, the collection is live and will shrink while you remove the elements).

Also, the [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) may return elements that are no rows of that table at all, resulting in the `NOT FOUND` exception you receive.

However, the simplest way to remove rows from a table is its [`deleteRow` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/table.deleteRow):

```
var table = document.getElementById('resultsTable');
while (table.rows.length > 0)
    table.deleteRow(0);
```

Comment: Interesting, I have hard coded the Title row which I'm guessing would be row 0. So I imagine I would need to change 0 to 1 and it would give the desired effect?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I just wanted to amend the answer that you can preserve the first rows by using a higher number than 0 :-)

Comment: Ok I tried that out and it removed all the rows except for the title so that's the perfect solution thank you! The next part of my code doesn't work now but I will work on it and see if I can fix it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` will return a `NodeList`, not a single node. You'll need to chose a node from that list, for example `document.getElementsByClassName('shiftTrRow')[0]`.

Also make sure that the node is actually a child of the given table. The following code is a little bit more exception safe:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('shiftTrRow'))
{    
    deleteRow = document.getElementsByClassName('shiftTrRow')[0];

    if(deleteRow.parentNode)
        deleteRow.parentNode.removeChild(deleteRow);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements. `table.removeChild` expects a DOM element, not an array, for its argument.

Comment: Ahh I understand, so even using this method I can't remove all the rows without using a loop? Still adding the [0] didn't resolve it so there must still be a problem somewhere.